# Change title and description dynamically

Tags: php, title

I would like to generate a dynamic title and description from pages that require MySQL queries:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    switch($page):
        case 'home':
            $body   = 'home.php';
            $title    = 'Home';  
        break;
    
        case 'contact':
            $body   = 'contact.php';
            $title    = 'Contact';  
        break;
    
        case 'members':
            $body   = 'members.php';
            $title    = 'I should put here the member profile';  
        break;
        
    /*
     * More pages
     */
        
        
    endswitch;

    ?>

    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        require_once $body;
    ?>
    
</body>
```

Then for instance I should call the pages, such as:

members.php page

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id = :mem_id";
/*
 * More codes
 */

foreach($res as $f):
    $mem_name       = $f['mem_name'];
endforeach;

$newTitle   = 'Profile of '.$meme_name;

 ?>
```

So **how can I put** the **$newTitle** generated from MySQL query inside the **title** tag

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the answer "Yes"?

Comment: Sorry, how can I put the title generated from MySQL query into the title tag?

Comment: I can call the pages, the problem is only with dynamic title

Comment: You would have to include `members.php` before setting the title. To do that, you need to update your code to return the body of each page in a variable and display that in the `<body>` tag. Your current problem is you require the `members.php` script AFTER you set the title, so there is no going back in this sense.

Comment: need to call ** require_once $body; **before $title** value set and set $newTitle value in    $title

Comment: as we can see, you can easily include that members.php to index.php or Vice Versa.

but we dont know what is the structures of you website

Comment: @JovylleBermudez The structure of the website is like above

Comment: @RomiHalasz: If I call members.php before the title, then the content of the page **members.php** will be between **head** tag and not inside body tag

Comment: @ImmoBroker i see, can you check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from the given code you can do below.
If you dont really wanted to rewrite your whole code.

**members.php**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id = :mem_id";
/*
 * More codes
 */

foreach($res as $f):
    $mem_name       = $f['mem_name'];
endforeach;

$newTitle   = 'Profile of '.$meme_name;

require_once $body;
 ?>

// put this at the buttom of your body
<script>
document.title="<?php echo $newTitle;?>"
</script>
```

But it will be still recomended that you should prepare your server side variables at the beginning so you will not face that kind of issue.

Comment: It works, this will not affect the fixed titles like **Contact** and **Home**, or I should do some checks before it

Comment: you can add some conditions if you dont want it to execute when $newTitle is not set..

Comment: In between, I've noticed that the title is added, but in the source code, is not added to the **title** tag, is this influencing the SEO crawling?